# Ubuntu 19.10 cursor freezes after long suspend

Tags: freeze, cursor

On Ubuntu 19.10, my cursor sometimes freezes (randomly) after a relatively long period of time not using the system, while in suspend. The keyboard works fine then, on resume, though. The cursor appears on the upper part of the screen, and doesn't move when I use the trackpad.

When using the computer normally, nothing special happens, the system works just fine, it's only when a longer time elpses not using it that this happens.

My laptop is a 2011 17" MacBookPro 6.2, where I'm only using the Intel videocard, as the Radeon card is defective. I boot 19.10 normally, and 19.10 runs very stable on this machine, unlike Elementary OS (even when bypassing the Radeon video card, it freezes). I also run 18.04 with Deepin DE and it is also stable, FYI. I never let it sleep for long enough to see if the issue happens there.

I have some Gnome extensions installed on 19.10.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that updating to 20.04 solves the issue

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-update
```

then

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

I performed it in graphical mode, it didn't pose any serious issue.

Good luck!